# Проблема выбора архитектуры при разработке Real-time Android приложения

Tags: java, android, база-данных, websocket, rest

## Задача:

Необходимо написать простое **Real-time** приложение на Android. Приложение может быть установлено на любой девайс и содержит такие компоненты:

- *EditText* (Вводим текстовую строку)
- *Кнопка* (Нажимаем на кнопку что-бы сохранить строку **в БД на удаленном сервере**)
- *Список* (Обновляем список добавлением этой строки **на всех устройствах**, где установлено приложение)

Плюшки типа **Firebase** к использованию **запрещены**.

## Аудитория:

Приложение будет установлено на **3000-5000** устройств.

## Описание проблемы:

С разработкой подобных проектов не сталкивался. В сети идет речь о использовании **WebSocket** дял решения данной задачи. Таким образом, меня беспокоят 2 вопроса, а именно:

1. *На чем лучше всего писать сервер и как его связать с БД?* Понятно, что-бы это дело было в связке с Websocket-ами. Может плохо искал, но
   примеров такой связки я не встретил в сети.
2. *Как обновить список на остальных устройствах, где установлено приложение?* Я так понимаю, мне нужно зарегестрировать айпишники устройств и на них отсылать ответ с сервера. Иначе, как же я узнаю кого нужно обновлять? Но так ли это или нет, хочу выяснить.

Буду рад любым вашим предложениям! Спасибо.

Comment: websocket + json rpc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз вопрос общий, отвечать буду тоже обще.

**Серверная часть**

Я бы выбрал для серверной части **node.js**, так как на нем есть вполне годные реализации вебсокета, и использовал бы с ним вместе **mongo db**. Настроить это все будет довольно просто.

**Клиентская часть**

Что касается клиентской части - сделайте хитро. Пока приложение открыто, держите открытым соединение с сервером и в реалтайме обновляйте все, что вам нужно. В фоне же (в случае, если вам нужно присылать пользователю уведомления), вы можете периодически открывать соединение, спрашивать у сервера все, что нужно, и если там есть обновления - обновляйте данные в приложении и присылайте уведомление пользователю.

Когда пользователь развернет приложение - подключаетесь к серверу, обновляетесь, держите коннект.

**Имейте в виду**, что во всех случаях инициатором соединения является клиент. Подключаться с сервера к клиенту лишино всякого смысла и часто является сложной задачей, ибо у клиентов часто нет **белого ip** и/или они сидят за **nat**.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! На счет *серверной* части: в принципе, я тоже подумывал на счет связки **Node.js + MongoDB**. Может посоветуете годную реализацию вебсокета? На счет *клиентской* части: т.е. если приложение работает в фоне, мне нужно написать **Service (службу)** и в ней открыть соединение с сервером? И такой *вопрос*, с чего посоветуете начать разработку такой системы?

Comment: @Tomas годную реализацию не послветую, ибо мне не приходилось пробовать разные. Чтобы работало в фоне, нужно создать сервис, да. Но если вам не нужно обновлять данные сразу, как они изменятся на сервере, то лучше не держать соединение открытым, а открывать его периодически и опрашивать сервер. Это поможет снизить расход батареи. Начать посоветую с изучения websocket, ибо для его открытия, к примеру, из java, нужно неплохо попариться со всякими сертификатами, насколько помню. И вообще, вы уверены, что хотите использовать именно вебсокет, а не, скажем, простое tcp соединение?

Comment: Я просто с вебсокетом чуточку разбирался. Эм, а как открыть tcp соединение и чем это лучше? На сервере ведь все равно будет работать вебсокет? Если не ошибаюсь, вебсокеты как раз таки работают поверх tcp....

Comment: @Tomas Вебсокет поверх tcp, мало того, websocket соединение инициализируется с помощью http запроса. Вебсокет используется в браузерах из-за браузерной политики. Если у вас клиент не браузер, а приложение андроид, то вы можете (и я бы сказал, что вам стоит) использовать tcp. С вебоскетом у вас будут летать дополнительные данные ws пакета, к тому же, нужно настраивать сертификаты, устанавливать соединение так, как этого требует стандарт ws и так далее. В общем, там, где можно обойтись без вебсокетов, их использовать не стоит.

Comment: Ну сейчас задам немного глупый вопрос: как открыть и использовать такое TCP соединение? А если я возьму библиотеку Socket.IO, не облегчит ли мне это жизнь и не избавит от тех проблем, которые вы описали в своем сообщении?

Comment: @Tomas socket.io работает поверх websocket. Вы вполне можете его использовать, однако зачем усложнять проект лишними зависимостями, если можно сделать проще? В таком случае для вес есть класс `Socket` в java и модуль `net` в node.js. К тому же, вы можете обойтись вообще без node.js, написав сервер на java. Бд выбрать по вкусу. Что касается настройки tcp соединения java-java, java-node.js - задайти вопрос с соответствующей темой, если возникнут вопросы.

Comment: Спабо большое за хороший совет! Буду разбираться.